# Stock prediction

Tags: regression, time-series, neural-networks

I'm working on a stock prediction algorithm using LSTM network. However my test data are obviously from different distribution than my train set [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ioAD.png), hence my prediction looks like the one on the figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6PRK.png). Some people use to normalize test data mean and std calculated from test set (or in case min max scaling min and max from test set) but I find it incorrect. So I would like to ask, if anyone has any idea, what should I do? thank you[image: Prediction]

[image: Data split]

with log(price)

[image: log prices]

Comment: Looks some exponential. Can you show a logarithmic scale (for $y$ (price) axis, $x$ still need to be linear) or a data sample? Thanks.

Comment: The data looks better, however it does not increase performance. I've uploaded figures as well.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, in the future, you should consider if similar types of questions may be better posted on the [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) SE site instead since it more specifically deals with statistics type questions.

Comment: Now it looks like $A+Bx^C$, [here](https://imgur.com/download/EigLApk/Image+for+comment+to+https%3A%2F%2Fmath.stackexchange.com%2Fq%2F3675132) is the image for $C=3$ so you can normalize data now. Maybe try to find more exact regression first, using values for $x\ge 3200$.